# jQuery: count those elements that have no attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, content-length

```
$("#mytable td").length;
```

counts the number of `td`s in the `#mytable`.

How to count among that `td`s only `td`s that have no attribute `class` (have no any classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although plalx's answer *may* work, it's delicate, but it's perfectly possible to have this:

```
<td class=""></td>
```

...which would match his selector. And in fact, it's quite common, particularly if you started out with a class on the cell but then removed it with `removeClass` or `toggleClass`.

To be sure, you do this:

```
var countWithNoClasses = $("#mytable td").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.className) === "";
}).length;
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/peca/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/peca/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that! Looks like my question was smarter than I expected :D

Comment: @Haradzieniec Make sure to trim the className as well in case you have something like `class=" "`.

Comment: "which would match his selector" should have been which would **not** match, but anyway I updated the answer already.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mytable td:not([class])").length;
```

The above will capture elements **without** a `class` attribute and the following will capture elements without a `class` attribute or with `class=""`.

```
$('#mytable td:not([class]), #mytable td[class=""]').length;
```

However you still might have issues with something like `class=" "` so using a filter function like already shown by T.J. Crowder would be safer.

```
$("#mytable td").filter(function() {
    //the replaces just trim the value
    return this.className.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '') === "";
}).length;
```